# Java ElasticSearch None of the configured nodes are available

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Just downloaded and installed elasticsearch 1.3.2 in past hour

Opened IP tables to port 9200 and 9300:9400

Set my computer name and ip in /etc/hosts

Head Module and Paramedic Installed and running smoothly

curl on localhost works flawlessy

copied all jars from download into eclipse so same version client

**--Java--**

```
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;


public class Test{         
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "elastictest").build();
            TransportClient transportClient = new TransportClient(settings);
                Client client = transportClient.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("143.79.236.xxx",9300));//just masking ip with xxx for SO Question

            try{
                SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch().setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("url", "twitter")).setSize(5).execute().actionGet();//bunch of urls indexed
                    String output = response.toString();
                        System.out.println(output);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                client.close();
        }
}
```

**--Output--**

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.elasticsearch.plugins).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:298)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:214)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClient.execute(InternalTransportClient.java:105)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.search(AbstractClient.java:330)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.search(TransportClient.java:421)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequestBuilder.doExecute(SearchRequestBuilder.java:1097)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:91)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:65)
    at Test.main(Test.java:20)
```

Update: Now I am REALLY confused. I just pressed run in eclipse 3 times. 2 times received the error above. 1 time the search worked!?? Brand new Centos 6.5 vps, brand new jdk installed. Then installed elasticsearch, have done nothing else to box.

**Update: After running ./bin/elasticsearch console**

```
[2014-09-18 08:56:13,694][INFO ][node                     ] [Acrobat] version[1.3.2], pid[2978], build[dee175d/2014-08-13T14:29:30Z]
[2014-09-18 08:56:13,695][INFO ][node                     ] [Acrobat] initializing ...
[2014-09-18 08:56:13,703][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Acrobat] loaded [], sites [head, paramedic]
[2014-09-18 08:56:15,941][WARN ][common.network           ] failed to resolve local host, fallback to loopback
java.net.UnknownHostException: elasticsearchtest: elasticsearchtest: Name or service not known
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkUtils.<clinit>(NetworkUtils.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.<init>(NettyTransport.java:204)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:86)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:98)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:837)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:57)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:45)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:52)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:837)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:57)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:45)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:98)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:837)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:57)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:45)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:98)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:52)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:837)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:57)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:45)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:98)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:837)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:57)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:45)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder$1.call(InjectorBuilder.java:200)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder$1.call(InjectorBuilder.java:193)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:830)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.loadEagerSingletons(InjectorBuilder.java:193)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.injectDynamically(InjectorBuilder.java:175)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:110)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:93)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ModulesBuilder.createInjector(ModulesBuilder.java:59)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.<init>(InternalNode.java:192)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:159)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:203)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:32)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: elasticsearchtest: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1469)
        ... 62 more
[2014-09-18 08:56:16,937][INFO ][node                     ] [Acrobat] initialized
[2014-09-18 08:56:16,937][INFO ][node                     ] [Acrobat] starting ...
[2014-09-18 08:56:17,110][INFO ][transport                ] [Acrobat] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/143.79.236.31:9300]}
[2014-09-18 08:56:17,126][INFO ][discovery                ] [Acrobat] elastictest/QvSNFajjQ9SFjU7WOdjaLw
[2014-09-18 08:56:20,145][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Acrobat] new_master [Acrobat][QvSNFajjQ9SFjU7WOdjaLw][localhost][inet[/143.79.236.31:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2014-09-18 08:56:20,212][INFO ][http                     ] [Acrobat] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/143.79.236.31:9200]}
[2014-09-18 08:56:20,214][INFO ][node                     ] [Acrobat] started
```

**--cluster config in elasticsearch.yml--**

```
################################### Cluster ###################################

# Cluster name identifies your cluster for auto-discovery. If you're running
# multiple clusters on the same network, make sure you're using unique names.
#
cluster.name: elastictest
```

Comment: Can you add elasticsearch log output to your question?

Comment: @eliasah thank u for your time, is that a switch I add at startup terminal command?

Comment: Has it finally worked?

Comment: can you check in your $ES_HOME/config/*.yml files where does the log go? and if your cluster's host is the one you are using in your Java app? No need to switch. But you can also start you elaticsearch service with the command line 'sudo service elasticsearch console' to see what's happening?

Comment: @BatScream it is not working (well 1/10 times it works). eliasah I will try that now and append output as an update. Thank you!

Comment: @eliasah thank you again. after running console out it seems there is some sort of UnknownHostException. Do I fix this in elasticsearch.yml or is this a centos issue?

Comment: This should be an error in your elasticsearch.yml configuration

Comment: @eliasah I added the computer name and ip to /etc/hosts and error went away. I also set network.host to my public ip in es.yml file, still same error though... Anywhere else in the es.yml I should be looking to configure? thank you again

Comment: what does elasticseachtest refer to?

Comment: that is the name of the vps server i added the public ip and that name to the /etc/hosts but added the ip (not the computer name) to the elasticsearch.yml file

Comment: Can you paste the section of your elasticsearch.yml file which says #########Cluster#########

Comment: I was suffering today from this problem and in addition to all the things mentioned a possible caused might be memory. In my case elasticsearch was starting fine but as soon as I tried to connect with the transport client it couldn't find the node and the server froze. Modifying the jvm.options file in /etc/elasticsearch and adjust the memory might help others

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Elasticsearch settings are in `$ES_HOME/config/elasticsearch.yml`. There, if the `cluster.name` setting is commented out, it means ES would take just about any cluster name. So, in your code, the `cluster.name` as `"elastictest"` might be the problem. Try this:

```
Client client = new TransportClient()
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(
                        "143.79.236.xxx",
                        9300));
```

Comment: thank you, I changed TransportClient client =... to just Client client =... and that may very well have done it. ^1. Please give me another min to test before I accept. Either way THANK YOU for your time, I am so appreciative!

Comment: Thanks. I set the cluster.name but forgot to add it in the Settings when creating the TransportClient.

Comment: `new InetSocketTransportAddress(
                        "143.79.236.xxx",
                        9300)` causes a compile error: `(InetAddress, int) cannot be applied to (String, int)`

Comment: @aliteralmind: I have updated the answer to remove the compile time error.

Comment: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient is an abstract class. How could you get instance by typing `new TransportClient()`?

Comment: @aliteralmind what did you do to solve this problem? I face the same one.

Comment: TransportClient has been replaced by RestHighLevelClient and will be removed in the next major release: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/_changing_the_client_8217_s_initialization_code.html

Answer (score 47):

#### possible problem:

1. wrong port, if you use a Java or Scala client, correct port is `9300`, not `9200`
2. wrong cluster name, make sure the cluster name you set in your code is the same as the cluster.name you set in `$ES_HOME/config/elasticsearch.yml`
3. the sniff option, set `client.transport.sniff` to be `true` but can't connect to all nodes of ES cluster will cause this problem too. [ES doc here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/2.3//transport-client.html) explained why.

Answer (score 16):

You should check the node's port, you could do it using head.
These ports are not same. Example,

The web URL you can open is `localhost:9200`,
but the node's port is `9300`, so none of the configured nodes are available if you use the `9200` as the port.

Answer (score 12):

```
NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{UfB9geJCR--spyD7ewmoXQ}{192.168.1.245}{192.168.1.245:9300}]]
```

In my case it was the difference in versions. If you check the logs in elasticsearch cluster you will see.

Elasticsearch logs

```
[node1] exception caught on transport layer [NettyTcpChannel{localAddress=/192.168.1.245:9300, remoteAddress=/172.16.1.47:65130}], closing connection
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received message from unsupported version: [5.0.0] minimal compatible version is: [5.6.0]
```

I was using elasticsearch client and transport version 5.1.1. And my elasticsearch cluster version was in 6. So I changes my library version to 5.4.3.

Answer (score 5):

Faced similar issue, and here is the solution

Example :

1. In elasticsearch.yml add the below properties

   ```
   cluster.name: production
   node.name: node1
   network.bind_host: 10.0.1.22
   network.host: 0.0.0.0
   transport.tcp.port: 9300
   ```
2. Add the following in Java Elastic API for Bulk Push (just a code snippet). 
   For IP Address add public IP address of elastic search machine

   ```
   Client client;
   BulkRequestBuilder requestBuilder;
   try {
       client = TransportClient.builder().settings(Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "production").put("node.name","node1")).build().addTransportAddress(
       new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(""), 9300));
       requestBuilder = (client).prepareBulk();
   } 
   catch (Exception e) {
   }
   ```
3. Open the Firewall ports for 9200,9300

Answer (score 5):

I spend days together to figure out this issue. I know its late but this might be helpful:

I resolved this issue by changing the compatible/stable version of:

```
Spring boot: 2.1.1
Spring Data Elastic: 2.1.4
Elastic: 6.4.0 (default)
```

Maven:

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
<version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
<artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You don't need to mention Elastic version. By default it is 6.4.0. But if you want to add a specific verison. Use below snippet inside  properties tag and use the compatible version of Spring Boot and Spring Data(if required)

```
<properties>
<elasticsearch.version>6.8.0</elasticsearch.version>
</properties>
```

Also, I used the Rest High Level client in ElasticConfiguration :

```
@Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
public String host;

@Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
public int port;

@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public RestHighLevelClient restClient1() {
    final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host, port));
    RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(builder);
    return client;
    }
}
```

Important Note: 
Elastic use 9300 port to communicate between nodes and 9200 as HTTP client. In application properties:

```
elasticsearch.host=10.40.43.111
elasticsearch.port=9200

spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=10.40.43.111:9300 (customized Elastic server)
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=any-cluster-name (customized cluster name)
```

From Postman, you can use: http://10.40.43.111:9200/[indexname]/_search

Happy coding :)

Comment: This is a great post!

Answer (score 3):

For completion's sake, here's the snippet that creates the transport client using proper static method provided by `InetSocketTransportAddress`:

```
    Client esClient = TransportClient.builder()
        .settings(settings)
        .build()
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("143.79.236.xxx"), 9300));
```

Comment: For now, use TransportAddress instead of InetSocketTransportAddress with the same parameters OR create client using RestClientBuilder (answer below)

Answer (score 3):

If the above advices do not work for you, change the **log level** of your logging framework configuration (log4j, logback...) to **INFO**. Then re-check the output.

The logger may be hiding messages like:

```
INFO  org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService - failed to get node info for...
Caused by: ElasticsearchSecurityException: missing authentication token for action...
```

(in the example above, there was X-Pack plugin in ElasticSearch which requires authentication)

Answer (score 3):

For other users getting this problem.

You may get this error if you are running a newer ElasticSearch (5.5 or later) while running Spring Boot <2 version.

Recommendation is to use the REST Client since the Java Client will be deprecated.

Other workaround would be to upgrade to Spring Boot 2, since that should be compatible.

See https://discuss.elastic.co/t/spring-data-elasticsearch-cant-connect-with-elasticsearch-5-5-0/94235 for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Since most of the ansswers seem to be outdated here is the setting that worked for me:

- **Elasticsearch-Version:** 7.2.0 (OSS) running on Docker
- **Java-Version:** JDK-11

elasticsearch.yml:

```
cluster.name: production
node.name: node1
network.host: 0.0.0.0
transport.tcp.port: 9300
cluster.initial_master_nodes: node1
```

Setup:

```
client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "production").build());
client.addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
```

Since PreBuiltTransportClient is deprecated you should use RestHighLevelClient for Elasticsearch-Version 7.3.0: https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client/7.3.0/index.html

Comment: do you have sample project?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java Transport client
1.check 9300 is access able /open.
2.check the node and cluster name ,this should be the correct,you can check the node and cluster name by type ip:port in your browser.
3.Check the versions of your jar and Es installed version.

Answer (score 0):

This one did work for me in ES 1.7.5:

```
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
    Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
            .put("client.transport.sniff",true)
            .put("cluster.name","elasticcluster").build();

    Client client = new TransportClient(settings)
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("[ipaddress]",9300));
    XContentBuilder builder = null;
    try {
        builder = jsonBuilder().startObject().field("user", "testdata").field("postdata",new Date()).field("message","testmessage")
                .endObject();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(builder.string());

    IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("twitter","tweet","1").setSource(builder).execute().actionGet();

    client.close();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This means we are not able to instantiate ES transportClient and throw this exception. There are couple of possibilities that cause this issue.

- Cluster name is incorrect. So open `ES_HOME_DIR/config/elasticserach.yml` file and check the cluster name value OR use this command: `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes'`
- Verify port 9200 is http port but elasticsearch service is using tcp port 9300 [by default]. So verify that the port is not blocked.
- Authentication issue: set the header in transportClient's context for authentication:

  ```
  client.threadPool().getThreadContext()
    .putHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encodeBase64String(basicHeader.getBytes()));
  ```

If you are still facing this issue then add the following property:

```
put("client.transport.ignore_cluster_name", true)
```

The below basic code is working fine for me:

```
Settings settings = Settings.builder()
            .put("cluster.name", "my-application").put("client.transport.sniff", true).put("client.transport.ignore_cluster_name", false).build();
    TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your elasticsearch.yml, "transport.host" property must be "0.0.0.0" not "127.0.0.1" or "localhost"

Comment: There is no such property "transport.host" in elasticsearch.yml. Theres only "network.host".

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late, incase the above answers didn't work, **I recommend checking the logs in elasticsearch terminal**. I found out that the error message says that i need to update my version from `5.0.0-rc1` to `6.8.0`, i resolved it by updating my maven dependencies to:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
  <version>6.8.0</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
  <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
  <version>6.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This changes my code as well, since `InetSocketTransportAddress` is deprecated. I have to change it to `TransportAddress`

```
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
               .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(host), port));
```

And you also need to add this to your **config/elasticsearch.yml** file (use your host address)

```
transport.host: localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the ES server logs

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log
```

I was using an outdated client

```
Received message from unsupported version: [5.0.0] minimal compatible version is: [6.8.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. my problem was that the version of the dependency had conflict with the elasticsearch version. check the version in ip:9200 and use the dependency version that match it

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue for ES version 5.6.10+. The thing is that Elasticsearch had the TransportClient, that was using PreBuild and has been deprecated on that version. The alternative (which is the solution here in case you are using ES 7.14 or earlier), is to use the Java High Level REST client. See the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high.html) (they also have a great migration guide to migrate an application from TransportClient to the REST client).

From the 7.15 version, they dropped Java High Level REST, in favor to Java API Client, and there’s also migration guides too. They did this mainly to reduce dependencies from the client. See [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/introduction.html).

If you are using the same version of client as the cluster, and the fit client library, the issue should be resolved.

Answer (score -1):

You should check logs
If you see like below
"stacktrace": ["java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received message from unsupported version: [6.4.3] minimal compatible version is: [6.8.0]"

You can check this link
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/java-client-or-spring-boot-for-elasticsearch-7-3-1/199778
You have to explicit declare es version.

Comment: Please provide more information besides just posting a link or post it as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried to implement elastic to spring boot application. But when I check elastic logs I face a issue which like that.                                                              ["java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received message from unsupported version: [6.4.3] minimal compatible version is: [6.8.0] . Spring boot sets  default version.(6.4.3) Therefore we need to change it. Because there is a version issue. Then I declare explicit es version in pom file.         <elasticsearch.version>7.3.0</elasticsearch.version>
Afterthat it works