# Elasticsearch NoNodeAvailableException None of the configured nodes are available

Tags: java, elasticsearch

```
Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
                .put("cluster.name", "logging_elasticsearch")
                .build();
        TransportClient client = TransportClient.builder()
                .settings(settings)
                .build()
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{10,100,30,62}), 9300));

  SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("logstash-2016.09.08")
            .setTypes("type1", "type2")
            .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("multi", "test"))                 // Query
            .setPostFilter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("age").from(12).to(18))     // Filter
            .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true)
            .execute()
            .actionGet();
```

[elasticsearch.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWzBc.png)
I'm getting a `NoNodeAvailableException` when executing my search query.

I tried this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33875764/2616923 
 but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, your code seems to be pretty close:

```
Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
        .put("cluster.name", "<elasticsearch-cluster-name>")
        .build();

Client client = new TransportClient.Builder()
            .settings(settings)
            .build()
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress("<elasticsearch-network-host>", <elasticsearch-transport-client-port|default 9300>)));
```

==== elasticsearch.yml ====

```
cluster.name: <elasticsearch-cluster-name>
node.name: <elasticsearch-network-host>
network.host: <elasticsearch-network-host>
network.bind_host: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put settings with node name like below,

```
Settings esSettings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", esClusterName)
.put("node.name",esNodeName)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I have created transport client with more parameters. Below code is perfectly running in production.

   Settings settingsBuilder = Settings.builder()
            .put("cluster.name", DBPropertyUtil.getPropertyByName("es.cluster")).put("client.transport.sniff", true).put("client.transport.ignore_cluster_name", true).build();

       Client client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settingsBuilder)
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(host), port));

Put respective details for host, port, clusterName as per your elasticSearch Servers config.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this error on a server with a fresh installation of Java and ElasticSearch, check that there is a JAVA_HOME environment setting and it is set to a correct path to the JRE. For example:

> JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_192