# No Node Available Exception Elasticsearch 5.0.2

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

First for all, i'm sorry for my english.
I have a problem with Java API Transport Client. I have one master node and three data nodes. Version of my Elasticsearch is 5.0.2 and i use 5.0.2 API.

I try to connect to my cluster with Transport Client and then i response

```
Exception in thread "main" NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{8SAZOxXXTU61DuDDMN-vGw}{XX.XX.X.XXX}{XX.XX.X.XXX:9300}, {#transport#-2}{Fv3729YgTGClRBo5T2mWpA}{XX.XX.X.XXX}{XX.XX.X.XXX:9300}, {#transport#-3}{Fr98ApBbRv29Xv6Mc8L4TQ}{XX.XX.X.XXX}{XX.XX.X.XXX:9300}, {#transport#-4}{JOmpSH4LRzuP_XInxQtD9Q}{XX.XX.X.XXX}{XX.XX.X.XXX:9300}]]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:328)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:226)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:339)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:403)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:80)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:54)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.get(ActionRequestBuilder.java:62)
    at nn.Main.main(Main.java:57)
```

That is my code of client:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequestBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchType;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;
import org.elasticsearch.xpack.client.PreBuiltXPackTransportClient;

public class Main {
    private static String[] hosts = new String[] {
            "XX.XX.X.XXX"
            ,"XX.XX.X.XXX"
            ,"XX.XX.X.XXX"
            ,"XX.XX.X.XXX"          
            };

    private static final Settings settings = Settings.builder()
            .put("cluster.name", "myCluster")
            .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
            .put("transport.tcp.port", 9300)
            .put("xpack.security.user", "transport_client_user:changeme")
            .build();
    private static final String index = "myIndex";
    private static final String type = "myType";
    private static TransportClient client;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {

        InetSocketTransportAddress[] ista = new InetSocketTransportAddress[hosts.length]; 

        for (int i = 0; i < hosts.length; i++) {
        ista[i] = new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(hosts[i]), 9300);
    }

        client = new PreBuiltXPackTransportClient(settings).addTransportAddresses(ista);        

        SearchRequestBuilder rb = client
                .prepareSearch(index)
                .setTypes(type)
                .setSearchType(SearchType.DEFAULT)
                .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("_id", 3524598));


        SearchResponse sResponse = rb.get();
        System.out.println(sResponse.toString());
    }
}
```

Port for transport client - 9300, all my nodes communicate under this port. I saw a lot like my question, and i trying to follow the advice contained in them. But i have the same exception.

If need more information or any files or settings of my Elastic - i'm ready to answer.

If it is important this is content of elasticsearch.yml

```
cluster.name: myCluster
node.name: elastic-0

path.data: /var/db/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
path.scripts: /usr/local/libexec/elasticsearch

network.host: _vmx0_

node.master: true 
node.data: false 
node.ingest: false 

node.attr.rack_id: rack_one
cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes: rack_id

discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["XX.XX.X.XXX","XX.XX.X.XXX","XX.XX.X.XXX","XX.XX.X.XXX","XX.XX.X.XXX"]

bootstrap.memory_lock: false

xpack.monitoring.exporters:
  id1:
    type: http
    host: ["XX.XX.X.XXX:9200"] 
    auth.username: remote_monitor 
    auth.password: changeme
```

I tried to change `TransportClient` on just `Client`, and disable `client.transport.sniff` but without result.

I will be very gratefull for any help or ideas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java ElasticSearch None of the configured nodes are available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25912572/java-elasticsearch-none-of-the-configured-nodes-are-available)

Comment: @Kulasangar no, other reason. XPack in elastic v5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason for which i received "NoNodeAvailableException".

The reason is transport_client's role  does not grant permission to view the data in all indices on default.
And i will to built my role for the access to data in indices.

Link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/5.0/built-in-roles.html

Comment: could you explain how did you do that? did you do it in your java code?@Valeriy

Comment: @user5621266, no, we just turn of security mode in x-pack xD  But if you want to know how to do this there is a link on dock: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/security-settings.html

Answer (score 0):

This exception usually occurs when we try to use ES with TranscientClient (9300) and not with an API (9200).

These could be the reasons behind this:

1. Our IP address or the port that is provided is wrong. By default, the transport communication happens via 9300 until and unless we explicitly change in the elastisearch.yml
2. The IP address and the port is not reachable from the machine where we are running the Java Application. The ES machine is simply not reachable from Client Machine so we need to open the port and IP to the client.
3. If we change the 'transport.host' then ES considers as a prod environment and makes bootstrap checks. But in the scenario where the environment is not prod and we are running ES in one machine and trying to hit it from another machine with a transport client (Java app) then we can just add 'discovery.type: single-node'.

Change the Elastic Search yaml as follows:

```
    cluster.name: elasticsearch
    node.name: node-1
    transport.host: 0.0.0.0
    transport.tcp.port: 9300
    http.port: 9200
    network.host: 0.0.0.0
    discovery.type: single-node
```